# Events in first week rendering close to the top in FulCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

I'm seeing a strange issue with a FullCalendar calendar I created on our Intranet.  Events on the first week are rendering very close to the top of the day, while all subsequent weeks, the event displays below the day number.

[image: FullCalendar Screenshot]

I don't know how to set up the CSS because the containing division is being positioned via tag attributes.

```
<div class="fc-event fc-event-hori fc-event-start fc-event-end Veterans"
  style="position: absolute; left: 407px; width: 96px; top: 19px;">

  <div class="fc-event-inner">
    <span class="fc-event-time">12a</span>
    <span class="fc-event-title">Companywide Toiletry Drive for
         Homeless Veterans</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried setting css to clear both

```
div.fc-day-content {
  clear:both;
}
```

But that hasn't worked.  I'm hesitant to put any margins on the fc-event div because that would affect all events, not just the top level ones.  Does anyone have an idea how to align the events correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I inadvertently fixed this issue while looking at another question.  When I set the class .fc-content-skeleton class in line 648 of fullcalendar.css (fullcalendar-2.1.1) to have:

```
height:108px;
```

That's the height of the calendar row in the demo file default.html.  Basically the div for class 'fc-content-skeleton' should have the same height as the div with the class 'fc-row'.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately, I am running version 2.0.2 and running 2.1.1 isn't an option due to the environment on which I'm hosting this (SharePoint 2007).  My users will just have to live with this until I can upgrade our server.

Comment: Well, I downloaded 2.0.2 to see if it had the same issue but it doesn't look like it does.  Anyway, good luck.

Comment: I have a feeling the issue is caused by SharePoint 2007.  I have to run an old version of jQuery because SP2007 runs as IE5.  I hate having that outdated server in place but I'm stuck with it for a while. Thanks for your help anyway.